# How to convert <span style="text-decoration: underline;">Name</span> to "<u>Name</u>"(basic HTML) in ASP.Net for SSRS reports?

Tags: html, asp.net, reporting-services

I have an issue in converting this tag(`<span style="text-decoration: underline;">Name</span>`) to (`<u>Name</u>`) in asp.net.

I need it for SSRS reporting since SSRS reporting does't support styles when  "Interpret the HTML tags as styles" is checked.

Note: **Name** can be anything based on the conditions from the above **spam** tag and the above script may contains different tags like 'underline,bold,italic' as styles.

Comment: Please show how you are converting the tag currently.

Comment: Hi Jsve,i am getting this tag(<span style="text-decoration: underline;">Name</span>) from Ajax HTML Editor and i want to convert this to (<u>Name</u>).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    string old_str = @"<span style=""font-weight:underline;"">John</span> <span style=""font-style: bold;"">Steve</span><span style=""text-weight:italic;"">Abrahem</span>";        


    string new_str1 = Regex.Replace(old_str, @"<span style=""font-weight:underline;"">(.*?)</span>", new MatchEvaluator(ReplaceUnderline)); 

string new_str2=Regex.Replace(new_str1, @"<span style=""font-style: bold;"">(.*?)</span>", new MatchEvaluator(ReplaceBold)); 

string new_str3=Regex.Replace(new_str2, @"<span style=""text-weight:italic;"">(.*?)</span>", new MatchEvaluator(ReplaceItalic)); 

        Console.WriteLine(new_str3);
    }

    static string ReplaceUnderline(Match m)
        {
    return "<ul>" + m.Groups[1] + "</ul>";
        }
    static string ReplaceBold(Match m)
        {
    return "<b>" + m.Groups[1] + "</b>";
        }

    static string ReplaceItalic(Match m)
        {
    return "<i>" + m.Groups[1] + "</i>";
        }
```

Comment: Please select this as answer since it works for you !

Comment: static string ReplaceUnderline(Match m)
        {
    return "<u>" + m.Groups[1] + "</u>";
        }

Answer (score 1):

In ASP.NET you could use regular expressions.

```
string old_str = @"<span style=""text-decoration: underline;"">Name</span>";
string new_str = Regex.Replace(old_str, "<.*?>", string.Empty);
```

Demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/wWMvpm

To find multiple occurrences

```
string old_str = @"<span style=""font-weight:underline;"">John</span> <span style=""font-style: underline;"">Steve</span> <span style=""text-decoration: underline;"">Abrahem</span>";
string new_str = Regex.Replace(old_str, "<.*?>(.*?)<.*?>", new MatchEvaluator(Replace)); 

static string Replace(Match m)
{
    return "<ul>" + m.Groups[1] + "</ul>";
}
```

Demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/M26VgU

Comment: Hi,thanks for the reply,could you please have a glance on my "Note:" as mentioned in the description.

Comment: Did you try my code? As you can see, Regex.Replace does not use any reference to "Name". It replaces all code between <...>, so it will work with any kind of html layout and any text, and not only "Name"

Comment: Hi,I've tried but it does't work for the scenario that i have mentioned.If then how to convert this '<span style="font-weight:underline;">John</span>
<span style="font-style: underline;">Steve</span>
 <span style="text-decoration: underline;">Abrahem</span>' .This code is from data base.

Comment: Hi smirnov,see this code and it does't work for this kind of script.   'string old_str = @"<span style=""text-decoration: underline;"">Name</span><span style=""text-decoration: bold;"">Name</span>";
  
  string new_str = Regex.Replace(old_str, "<.*?>", string.Empty);
   
  Console.WriteLine("<ul>" + new_str + "</ul>");'

Comment: Have you seen my second example with MatchEvaluator?

Comment: Yes,but it works for only one statement.What if the script having many statements or tags? like I said in the **Note** above.

Comment: I don't think you tested the code with MatchEvaluator, because it should work for multiple "statements". If you still have a problem - create and share your code at https://dotnetfiddle.net

Comment: Thank you so much smirnov. See my final answer.

Comment: Please create and share your code at dotnetfiddle.net

Answer (score 0):

Also check this and you can make your own changes. https://dotnetfiddle.net/wgHV6p